# How do I turn off this "Hidden Line" mode in wireframe view?

Tags: 3d-view, wireframe

Somehow I have turned on a kind of hidden line mode for the wireframe view. How do I turn this off?
[image]

[image]

It does not appear to be an issue with "Alt Z" or the X-Ray settings suggested below.

Here is a OneDrive link to the file. I'm not sure how else to share it.

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnO4dbJhL5pfgbQVYDDO3OYEtoTOwg?e=PbU5BO

Comment: What does it give if you Alt Z?

Answer (score 0):

Is that multiple objects in object mode?
It might be X ray turned to 1. Put it back to 0 or uncheck it

[image]

[image]

Comment: This does not seem to be the issue. I am not sure how to explain it.
I will attach more pictures and a link to the file itself, as the behavior follows the file around.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It looks fine when I open it so I don't know what to tell you.

Have you tried just making a new blender file and just appending all the collections?
If this issue is only on this file that should fix it.

Comment: Hmmm. It appeared the same for me on both my computers. However, I have found a way to fix it for me. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

Well not sure why, but here is what I did to fix it. I have tried it twice now and it has worked both times.

First go to wireframe view, then select all objects, then go into edit mode, then hit "Alt Z", then go out of edit mode, then hit "Alt Z" again. An it fixed it.